# zf tool & PHPunit not recognised in include_path

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

I've be struggling with this for a while.

When using the zf tool included in the Zend Framework 1.11 to both create projects and actions and so on, I always get the notice that PHPUnit was not found in the include path and hence the test have not automatically been created. I know that this is only a notice and not an error however I would like it to work.

I am using OS X 10.7 and MAMP, my include path in MAMP is as follows:

```
include_path = ".:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/PHPUnit"
```

The only hint of the problem I have found so far on the internet is that the zf tool is using the natively installed php and include path and hence not noticing the PHPUnit.

I suppose that I could find the php.ini file and add the PHPUnit to it's include path but it feels a little bit of a hack.

Is there away to "prioritise" php installs?

Thank you for you help.

Al

Comment: Just to make sure, is it looking for `PHPUnit_Framework_Something` or for the `phpunit` binary itself? I ask because I believe that the tool executes PHPUnit to generate the tests. Can you copy-and-paste the actual error message?

Comment: Hi David, I'm not quite sure what it is trying to execute, I had presumed that it was looking to see if I had phpunit installed and whether to bother building the tests. The "error" (or note rather) message when creating a project is as follows: `Testing Note: PHPUnit was not found in your include_path, therefore no testing actions will be created.` and if i was to create an action say i get `Note: PHPUnit is required in order to generate controller test stubs.` I hope that helps.

Comment: What do you get if you enter `which phpunit` at the command line?

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found the answer at http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Zend_framework

Basically follow Step 5.

Replace

```
# find php: pear first, command -v second, straight up php lastly
if test "@php_bin@" != '@'php_bin'@'; then
    PHP_BIN="@php_bin@"
elif command -v php 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
    PHP_BIN=`command -v php`
else
    PHP_BIN=php
fi
```

with

```
PHP_BIN=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php
```

Thank for your help anyway.