# Ubuntu, zend framework and PHPUnit - Testing Note: PHPUnit was not found in your include_path, therefore no testing actions will be created

Tags: zend-framework, ubuntu, phpunit, include-path

I have fresh instalation of Zend Framework on my ubuntu. I've just installed PHPUnit. I could use it from terminal. Everything works fine. I've added manually PHPUnit path to include_path in php.ini used by apache and for PHP CLI. Apache restarts without any problem.

But if I use: `zf.sh create project myproject` I get information: `Testing Note: PHPUnit was not found in your include_path, therefore no testing actions will be created.`

I think I tested all solutions I have found in internet... please help me.

Comment: I'm curious about this answer, I've not been able to get PHPUnit working in my Ubuntu 11.10 either.

Comment: How did you install PHPUnit?  via PEAR?  If so, I would try uninstalling via PEAR and install using apt-get.

Comment: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/installation.html - here is information that installation via pear is only one correct method. Or I could try to do this manually...

Comment: See if [this similar question for Mac OS/X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969052/zf-tool-phpunit-not-recognised-in-include-path) helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, maybe this will help someone with the same situation like me. I couldn't solve this so I started everything from the scratch. I made new instalation of Ubuntu 11.10. Then I installed MySQL, Apache, PHP and additional packages for PHP using this [tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-11.10-lamp). Next I installed PHPUnit using this [article](http://konradpodgorski.com/blog/213/how-to-install-phpunit-on-ubuntu-11-10-and-get-it-to-work/). Everything worked fine. So I started to search for best way of Zend Framework installation. I have found many articles, blogs etc, but it doesn't work.

So I downloaded framework from zend site, unpacked it. Inside zf directory i changed name of bin for zend-bin, and library for Zend. Then I copied zend-bin to /usr/local and Zend to /usr/share/php and created link to us zf command (`ln -s /usr/local/zend-bin/zf.sh /usr/bin/zf`) Next I changed include_path in php.ini for CLI added /usr/share/php/Zend path.

Now everything work. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

First **install PHPUNIT** and after that put  **PHPUnit library in php include path**. and in Home directory **create a file with name ".zf.ini"** and add a line of your php include path `php.include_path=".:/usr/lib/php/pear"`

And for making autoload phpunit files for zf commands add below function in zf.php file

```
// For solving loading issue of PHPUNIT classs from pear folder
spl_autoload_register(function($class)
{   
        $file = str_replace('_','/',$class.'.php');

        //Suppress errors in case it can't find the file.
        @include_once $file;
});
```

I hope this will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Zend_Tool sometimes doesn't seem to respect include paths. Try putting something like this in your ~/.zf.ini

```
php.include_path = "/usr/share/php:/path/to/zf/library"
```

Comment: I have full include_path in .zf.ini .